# Someone whose ancestors were artists

Tags: idiom-requests

How would you succinctly describe someone whose parents and ancestors were artists ?

I thought about: "He has artist lineage."

Or: "He comes from an artist family."

Comment: A family of artists, although that suggests siblings are also artists.

Answer (score 2):

**She comes from a long line of artists.**

> **a long line of** ​:
>   a series of people or things that follow each other
>   in time:
>
> She is the latest in a long line of controversial leaders. He comes
>   from a long line of doctors (= a lot of his relatives were doctors
>   before him)
>   [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/line)